# How to position background image in bottom right corner? (CSS)

Tags: css, background

I have a 500x500 px image which is set as a background image on my website (as background-image of `<body>`) But I need this image to be located in a bottom right corner of the webpage. How can I achieve this? (better with css method)

Thank You.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Voilà:

```
body {
   background-color: #000; /*Default bg, similar to the background's base color*/
   background-image: url("bg.png");
   background-position: right bottom; /*Positioning*/
   background-repeat: no-repeat; /*Prevent showing multiple background images*/
}
```

The background properties can be combined together, in one background property. 
See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position

Comment: Thnx, y've helped me quiet a lot today )))

Comment: @Legionar Works fine for me, in Chrome 43 & Firefox 38.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, it was working, but `jquery` was changing `bottom` to `0`... :-/

Comment: I had to add `background-attachment: fixed;` to get this to work properly

Comment: This may not work as expected if the body element size is smaller than the viewport / content size. Adding `background-attachment: fixed;` as suggested in a comment avoids that issue.

Answer (score 24):

for more exactly positioning:

```
      background-position: bottom 5px right 7px;
```

Comment: Well done for providing example on fine-tuning background image alignment relative to the "docking point" via pixels

Comment: This is a more flexible approach. Well done.

Answer (score 13):

This should do it:

```
<style>
body {
    background:url(bg.jpg) fixed no-repeat bottom right;
}
</style>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Answer (score 8):

Did you try something like:

```
body {background: url('[url to your image]') no-repeat right bottom;}
```