# How to align background image in bottom of website, when its higher then screen height?

Tags: css

I have a 2000x2000 px image which is set as a background image on my website (as background-image of `<body>`), but I need this image to be aligned in bottom of the webpage. How can I achieve this?

My CSS is:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
    background: url('../images/pozadie.jpg') left bottom repeat-x;
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729652/how-to-position-background-image-in-bottom-right-corner-css) is not working, when background image is higher than screen height...

Comment: Sorry, my fault, it was working, but `jquery` was changing `bottom` to `0`... :-/

Answer (score 4):

Please try with this.

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
    background: url('../images/pozadie.jpg') repeat-x 0 0;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Plus 1, Sorry, my fault, it was working, but `jquery` was changing `bottom` to `0`... :-/

Answer (score 2):

Use the [background-attachment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) property

```
body {
    background: url('../images/pozadie.jpg') left bottom repeat-x;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Plus 1, Sorry, my fault, it was working, but `jquery` was changing `bottom` to `0`... :-/