# jQuery interfering with CSS Background Image Position?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having problems positioning my background images to the "bottom". When I try to set its position to bottom, it actually moves my image even further up the top so that the upper portion is cut off. I was searching for what might be causing this and saw someone mentioned that "jQuery was setting bottom to 0". (Found [here actually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729652/how-to-position-background-image-in-bottom-right-corner-css))

This is occurring even on this [simple test editor](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-image_position) and has left me at a loss as to what to do.

Is anyone familiar with this and how to fix it?

Comment: since the background image is set to the body element, it strictly depends on the height of body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an optical illusion because the height of the body is too small to observe the change properly. Add this to the body CSS and you will see the actual placement, try it with different variations of the body background image position

```
border: solid red 2px;
margin:0px;
height:500px;
```